# Do I need an object within an object in java? Need to keep track of multiple things in array.

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

Alright well I have one method that gets the name and wage of a worker.. 
in my class definition I have where it creates an object whether they input nothing, a name, or a name and wage.

So then for each worker I need to ask for tips (which there can be multiple clients who tip). I have this in another method and I prompt for the tip but I'm not sure how to only add the tips to the specific worker.. ie. when I run the program, the output is correct for this first worker (salary, tips, avg tips) and if I add another worker the tips are wrong because it is not separated, rather it is continuing to add all the tips from each worker

```
private static void addWorker(){

    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name?");
    wage = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Wage?"));

    worker object = new worker(name, wage);
    workerArray[count] = object;

    addWorkerTip();

    count++;
}

private static void addWorkerTip(){
    do{
            tip = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"tip?"));

                            numTips++;
                totalWorkerTips = tip + totalWorkerTips;
            worker.addTips(totalWorkerTips);

    }while (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Another Worker?") == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
}
```

Comment: addWorkerTip should be receiving the worker as a parameter.  Or addWorkerTip should be a method of worker.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset tip back to 0 at the end of the do loop so it can accept a new value without adding the previous value.

```
tip = 0;
```

or you could create a tip array and store each tip value in the array

Answer (score 0):

You should make a class called worker with proper instance variables.

```
public class Worker{
private String name;
private double wage;
private double tip;

public Worker(){
name=null;
wage=null;
tip=0;
}

public Worker(String n){
name=n;
tip=0;
}

public Worker(String n, double w){
name = n;
wage = w;
tip=0;
}

public void setWage(double newWage){
wage = newWage;
}

public void addTip(double newTip){
tip+=newTip;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach your class structure,

```
private static class Worker {
  private String name;
  private double wage;
  private double tip = 0;

  Worker(String name, double wage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.wage = wage;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public double getWage() {
    return wage;
  }

  public void addTip(double tip) {
    this.tip += tip;
  }
  public double getTipe() {
    return this.tip;
  }
}

// Use a Collection of Worker(s) - not an array.
private List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<Worker>();

public void addWorker() {
  String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name?");
  double wage = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
      .showInputDialog(null, "Wage?"));

  Worker worker = new Worker(name, wage);
  double tip = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
      .showInputDialog(null, "tip?"));
  worker.addTip(tip);
  workers.add(worker); // Add the worker to the List.
}
```